# What is the mathematical relationship between "no. of rows affected" and "execution time" of a sql query?

Tags: sql, math, set, relation, calculus

The query remains constant i.e it will remain the same.

e.g. a select query takes 30 minutes if it returns 10000 rows.

Would the same query take 1 hour if it has to return 20000 rows?

I am interested in knowing the mathematical relation between **no. of rows(N)** and **execution time(T)** keeping other parameters as constant(K).

i.e T= N*K or

T=N*K + C or

any other formula?

Reading http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/76556/progress.pdf if it helps. Anybody who can understand this before me, please do reply. Thanks...

Comment: Load on the machine will come into play as well.  The numbers you get from local tests might not match what'll happen when you execute the same query in production.

Comment: This is basically a production concern only. I am thinking of logging no. of records and actual execution times for various runs of a ssis job so that we can estimate the time based on the no. of records. I think my formula T=N*K + C, should work for average values of K and C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that is good question :), but there is not exact formula, because it depends of execution plan.

SQL query optimizer could choose another execution plan on query which return different number of rows. 
I guess if the query execution plan is the same for both query's and you have some "lab" conditions then time growth could be linear. You should research more on sql execution plans and statistics

Comment: Not only that, query plans have different growth characteristics. A merge join on sorted data would be linear in the input size, but nested loops would be quadratic, for example. Also, need to think about cache effects. Reading from disk is slow compared to reading from memory.

Comment: @Laurence: Can you post a link or little bit elaborate explanation of what you said? Would it be strictly linear for select/insert/update without joins (T=N*K or T=N*K + C). I am thinking on having a generalised formula for estimated execution time for some of the SSIS jobs we are running. e.g. if I estimate a job to run for 5 hours, it should be ok if it finishes in 4 or 6 hours. But if it takes more than 6 hours or less than 3 hours then the formula fails.

Comment: For selecting from a single table with no where, group by or order then the worst case will be linear and based on the random seek time of your storage. However, if you have a clustered index it is more likely to be based on the streaming throughput of the storage.

Answer (score 2):

Take the very simple example of reading every row in a single table.

In the worst case, you will have to read every page of the table from your underlying storage. The worst case for this is having to do a random seek. The seek time will dominate all other factors. So you can estimate the total time.

```
time ~= seek time x number of data pages
```

Assuming your rows are of a fairly regular size, then this is linear in the number of rows.

However databases do a number of things to try and avoid this worst case. For example, in SQL Server table storage is often allocated in extents of 8 consecutive pages. A hard drive has a much faster streaming IO rate than random IO rate. If you have a clustered index, reading the pages in cluster order tend to have a lot more streaming IO than random IO.

The best case time, ignoring memory caching, is (8KB is the SQL Server page size)

```
time ~= 8KB * number of data pages / streaming IO rate in KB/s
```

This is also linear in the number of rows.

As long as you do a reasonable job managing fragmentation, you could reasonably extrapolate linearly in this simple case. This assumes your data is much larger than the buffer cache. If not, you also have to worry about the cliff edge where your query changes from reading from buffer to reading from disk.

I'm also ignoring details like parallel storage paths and access.